# solidity what is "tx" when making a transaction

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

am quite a beginner in solidity and I have been playing with truffle, When I send a transaction, I get a transaction log and one of the values is "tx", the other labels are quite self explanatory but I don't really understand what this one represents?

So what does it represent/what can you do with this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tx` stands for "transaction", but it is two different things depending on if you're talking about Solidity or Truffle.

---

[The "Block and Transaction Properties" docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) for Solidity say that `tx` is one of the globally available variables.

> There are special variables and functions which always exist in the global namespace and are mainly used to provide information about the blockchain or are general-use utility functions.

According to the same docs, there should be two global fields on it:

- `tx.origin`

> sender of the transaction (full call chain)

- `tx.gasprice`

> gas price of the transaction

---

[The "Processing Transaction Results" docs](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts.html#processing-transaction-results) for Truffle  state that `tx` is a string containing the transaction hash.

> When you make a transaction, you're given a result object that gives you a wealth of information about the transaction.
>
> [...] Specifically, you get the following:
>
> ```
> result.tx (string) - Transaction hash
>
> result.logs (array) - Decoded events (logs)
>
> result.receipt (object) - Transaction receipt (includes the amount of gas used)
> ```
>
> For more information, please see the [README](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/contract) in the `@truffle/contract` package.